IntelliSense in VS Code Not Recognizing tsconfig.json for New .ts Files in Angular Project
I'm encountering an issue with Visual Studio Code's IntelliSense not recognizing my tsconfig.json when I create a new .ts file directly in the editor. Instead, it generates a jsconfig.json file. However, when I create a component using the terminal command npm run ng generate component ..., the generated .ts file correctly recognizes the tsconfig.json. This behavior is consistent across different branches in my project, and I haven't encountered this issue in other projects.
Additionally, if I rename a .ts file created via the terminal command, it again fails to recognize the tsconfig.json.
Here's the structure of my project:
    .
    ├── .vscode
    ├── e2e
    ├── node_modules
    ├── patches
    ├── src
    │   ├── app
    │   ├── assets
    │   └── ...
    ├── .browserslistrc
    ├── .editorconfig
    ├── .gitignore
    ├── angular.json
    ├── karma.conf.js
    ├── ngcc.config.js
    ├── package.json
    ├── package-lock.json
    ├── README.md
    ├── tsconfig.app.json
    ├── tsconfig.base.json
    ├── tsconfig.json
    ├── tsconfig.spec.json
    └── tslint.jsonz

tsconfig.json:
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ]
}

Angular 14.2.8
node 10.15.0
VS Code
Terminal
Node version
I haven't visited this project for a while, and there have been several updates accumulated. Additionally, in another project, I installed ESLint and Prettier plugins, which might have influenced my expectations or the environment setup.
